# CakePHP 2.0 REST Error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a simple CakePHP 2.0 application setup. I followed the simple instructions in the book for setting up a simple REST service here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

However when i try to access via /controller/index.xml
I receive an Invalid Input and Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred. With the following Stack

```
Trace:
#0 /var/www/yoyo/lib/Cake/Utility/Xml.php(87): Xml::fromArray(Array, Array)
#1 /var/www/yoyo/app/View/Offers/xml/index.ctp(3): Xml::build(Array)
#2 /var/www/yoyo/lib/Cake/View/View.php(598): include('/var/www/yoyo/a...')
#3 /var/www/yoyo/lib/Cake/View/View.php(365): View->_render('/var/www/yoyo/a...')
#4 /var/www/yoyo/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(898): View->render(NULL, NULL)
#5 /var/www/yoyo/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(114): Controller->render()
#6 /var/www/yoyo/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(89): Dispatcher-    >_invoke(Object(OffersController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#7 /var/www/yoyo/app/webroot/index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest),      Object(CakeResponse))
#8 {main}
```

Thanks in Advance!
-michael

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when using $this->Model->find(), you're passing each Model and associated model in this form:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [MainModel] => Array
        (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => foo
        )
        [AssocModelOne] => Array
        (
                [id] => 23
                [name] => bar
        )
        [AssocModelTwo] => Array
        (
                [id] => 87
                [name] => baz
        )
    )
)
```

The XML parser doesn't want to see numerics as the top level of the array. But it also only wants to see ONE top level item. When you pass more than one like below, you end up with the "Invalid Input" 500 error:

```
Array
(
    [MainModel] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => foo
    )

    [AssocModelOne] => Array
    (
        [id] => 23
        [name] => bar
    )

    [AssocModelTwo] => Array
    (
        [id] => 87
        [name] => baz
    )
)
```

This array is NOT going to work. To get it to work in this manner, you MUST place the data inside of another array that is considered the "top level" before using it, or it will fail. So it should look more like:

```
Array
(
[ModelData] => Array
    (
        [MainModel] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => foo
        )

        [AssocModelOne] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [name] => bar
        )

        [AssocModelTwo] => Array
        (
            [id] => 87
            [name] => baz
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why, but this code works...

in your xml/index.ctp:

```
<?php $xml = Xml::build(array('offers' => array('offer' => $offers))); echo $xml->saveXML(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say you access via `/controller/index.xml` you mean `GET /offers.xml`, right? Anyway, It is hard for me to figure out what's wrong with the information provided. Could you please show the code on your `routes.php` and `/xml/index.ctp`?

Edit: "An internal Error has occurred" does not look like a PHP error, but the trace suggests there was one. Could you please confirm that's the only information you're getting about the error? Also, as it seems there's a problem with the `Xml::fromArray` function, could you please show the code on the index action?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes that's offers.xml, in routes.php i added: 
    Router::mapResources(array('offers','categories'));
    Router::parseExtensions();

my xml/index.ctp:
    $xml = Xml::build($offers);
    echo $xml->asXML();

also in my OffersController index function:
    $offers = array('Offers' => $this->Offer->find('all'));
    $this->set(compact('offers'));

Comment: After adding some data, I am now getting a bunch of DOMDocument::createElement() errors, and String could not be parsed as XML, followed by an Internal Error has Occurred

Comment: Your index action seems weird to me, but I can't say that's the issue. Just to be sure, please change it to:

`function index() {
        $offers = $this->Offer->find('all');
        $this->set(compact('offers'));
    }`

Comment: I just noticed you are doing `echo $xml->asXML();` and I think you're assuming `$xml` is an instance of the XmlHelper? Be that the case or not, the truth is that `$xml` is the result of `Xml::build($offers)` which would be whether a `SimpleXMLElement` or `DOMDocument` instance and none of them have an `asXML()` method. Please use `echo $xml->saveXML();` as the documentation suggests.